# How long should meat be brined for in a 10 percent solution?

Tags: brining

I use a 10 percent salt solution for my brines. It just seems the easiest. 100 grams of salt per liter of water, but I have read that this is a bit high as most books speak of a 6 percent solution.

So I would like to know how long should you brine meat for at this solution? What time with this solution should you brine per kg of meat and does this differ between poultry, fish and red meat?

Just a rough estimation would be great as I don't want to over salt the food.

Comment: *confused* it sounds like you're currently doing fine with a 10% solution—surely you'd know (from tasting it) if it were oversalted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what meat and cut you are brining, and how you intend to treat the meat after brining.  You may need to experiment, anything from 50% to 100% of the time your recipe book suggest.  Search for brining guidelines and other useful information, there are a large community that have a lot of knowledge and experience.